# How to sort the column names according to a single row in a database wish stores priority values

Tags: django

I have this table that i want to sort the column names and get them in django according to page priorities , my table is :

```
---------------------------------
Type  | Home  | Schedule |  AddUser
---------------------------------
Admin |   2    |    1     |    3
---------------------------------
```

I want to get in django as a collection Schedule , Home , AddUser how can i do it in an easy way?

Comment: A table in a database? This looks a rather strange modeling for a database (normally you should not *pivote* your database).

Comment: this is a query of a table i want to get the model names according to the integers

Comment: for example Schedule Home AddUser